# Transparent control backgrounds on a VB.NET gradient filled form?

Tags: vb.net, winforms

I'm filling the background of some VB.NET 2005 WinForms form with a nice pretty gradient fill (by overriding the OnPaint event). This works fine but the various labels etc on the form show with a solid background even after I set the BackColor to Color.Transparent. Setting the transparency key of the form itself seems to affect this but I cannot get the labels to have a truely transparent BackColor, is there an easy way to get around this or am I looking at custom controls etc?

Answer (score 4):

Add a new class to your project and paste the code shown below.  Build.  Drop the new control from the top of your toolbox onto your form.

```
Public Class TransparentLabel
    Inherits Label

    Public Sub New()
        Me.SetStyle(ControlStyles.Opaque, True)
        Me.SetStyle(ControlStyles.OptimizedDoubleBuffer, False)
    End Sub

    Protected Overrides ReadOnly Property CreateParams() As System.Windows.Forms.CreateParams
        Get
            Dim cp As CreateParams = MyBase.CreateParams
            cp.ExStyle = cp.ExStyle Or &H20  ' Turn on WS_EX_TRANSPARENT
            Return cp
        End Get
    End Property
End Class
```

The flicker might be noticeable, no fix.

Answer (score 1):

After some experimentation I've found that the following works for gradiant filling form backgrounds and preserving label transparency:

```
Protected Overrides Sub OnPaint(ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.PaintEventArgs)

    Dim formGraphics As Graphics = e.Graphics
    Dim gradientBrush As New LinearGradientBrush(New Point(0, Height), New Point(0, 0), Me.AppSettings.FormGradiantFrom, Me.AppSettings.FormGradiantTo)

    formGraphics.FillRectangle(gradientBrush, ClientRectangle)

End Sub
```

And in the form load event:

```
SetStyle(ControlStyles.AllPaintingInWmPaint Or ControlStyles.DoubleBuffer Or _
               ControlStyles.ResizeRedraw Or ControlStyles.UserPaint, True)
```

Comment: I implemented the solution described but I got a problem: when I drag my form, the background it captured in the previous position is dragged to the new position...