# Form background color set to tint color

Tags: .net, winforms, colors, background

How can I set the background color for a form as specified in the attached image?

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One way would be to directly use the image as the form's `BackgroundImage`.

If you want to achieve this proceduarally (more flexible), you can manually paint the form's background using `OnPaintBackground`:

```
protected override void OnPaintBackground(PaintEventArgs e)
{
    using (var brush = new LinearGradientBrush
               (DisplayRectangle, Color.Black, Color.DarkGray, LinearGradientMode.Vertical))
    {
        e.Graphics.FillRectangle(brush, DisplayRectangle);
    }
}

protected override void OnResize(EventArgs e)
{
    base.OnResize(e);
    Invalidate(); // Force repainting on resize
}
```

**Result**:

[image: Gradient]

Comment: This works well for me but here is one problem which i face is that i have two button on left bottom and right bottom edge. when i maximize this form then both button are placed on middle. Anchoring of both button is set but problem occurs when i maximize the form

Comment: Make sure the anchors are set to "Bottom, Left" and "Bottom, Right" respectively.

Comment: My mistake. I just reverse the position of button few minute ago but forgot to set anchors again. Now work well. Thanks you very much

Answer (score 2):

Use can use `OnPaint event` of the `winform` and there you can do some modifications. Check the specified links to know in details about this.

Use the `LinearGradientBrush` to do this as:

/* Take a Linear Gradient Brush */

```
LinearGradientBrush brush = new LinearGradientBrush(rect, Color.Orange, Color.Orchid, LinearGradientMode.ForwardDiagonal);
```

Code Snippet of OnPaint Overload:

```
 Protected Overrides Sub OnPaint(ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.PaintEventArgs)

        ' Declare a variable of type Graphics named formGraphics.

        ' Assign the address (reference) of this forms Graphics object

        ' to the formGraphics variable.

        Dim formGraphics As Graphics = e.Graphics

        ' Declare a variable of type LinearGradientBrush named gradientBrush.

        ' Use a LinearGradientBrush constructor to create a new LinearGradientBrush object.

        ' Assign the address (reference) of the new object

        ' to the gradientBrush variable.

        Dim gradientBrush As New LinearGradientBrush(New Point(0, 0), New Point(Width, 0), Color.White, Color.DarkMagenta)



        ' Here are two more examples that create different gradients.

        ' Comment the Dim statement immediately above and uncomment one of these

        ' Dim statements to see how varying the two colors changes the gradient result.

        ' Dim gradientBrush As New LinearGradientBrush(New Point(0, 0), New Point(Width, 0), Color.Chartreuse, Color.SteelBlue)

        ' Dim gradientBrush As New LinearGradientBrush(New Point(0, 0), New Point(Width, 0), Color.White, Color.SteelBlue)



        formGraphics.FillRectangle(gradientBrush, ClientRectangle)

    End Sub
```

**Another Way is use `OnPaintBackground` event and use `LinearGradientBrush`** ref:[MSDN](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/fi-FI/winforms/thread/95b93920-9bb4-484a-8947-75719b8dce2d)

```
protected override void OnPaintBackground(PaintEventArgs e) {
      Rectangle rc = new Rectangle(0, 0, this.ClientSize.Width, this.ClientSize.Height);
      using (LinearGradientBrush brush = new LinearGradientBrush(rc, Color.Red, Color.Blue, 45F)) {
        e.Graphics.FillRectangle(brush, rc);
      }
```

Reference:
[How to Add a Gradient Background to a Win Form with VB.NET & VB2005](http://www.getdotnetcode.com/nexDotNet/030005H2GradientBg4WinFormVB/H2GradientBg4WinFormVB.htm)
[Windows Forms 2.0-Draw Beautiful Gradient Backdrops](http://nickmasao.wordpress.com/2008/11/17/windows-forms-20-draw-beautiful-gradient-backdrops/)
[Set Gradient/Shaded Background to Windows form using c#](http://codeindex.blogspot.com/2011/12/set-gradientshaded-background-to.html)

Check `Resize` related information here:
`this.Invalidate()` -
[Create a Gradient background on your Forms or Controls](http://www.knowdotnet.com/articles/lineargradient.html)

check this SO thread also..
[Transparent control backgrounds on a VB.NET gradient filled form?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/511320/transparent-control-backgrounds-on-a-vb-net-gradient-filled-form)